# Call function from generic component Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 9 and I have a data strcture as follow:
`myMap: Map<key: string, value: {component: any, data: string}>`

I have 3 elements in my map, the first attribute of my value object is a Component type. I use it to create dynamically new components Like:

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.myMap.get(compName).component);
this.container.clear();
const comp = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

Now I want to call the function of the created component. All the components have one function in common (for example `foo(string)`) but implemented differently in each component. How can I call this function.
I tried to do:
`(<this.myMap.get(compName).component>comp.instance).foo('abcd');`
However I have a compilation error.

An example of my map object:

```
myMap: Map<key: string, value: {component: any, data: string}> = [
    ['compA', {comp: AComponent, data: 'A'}],
    ['compB', {comp: BComponent, data: 'B'}],
    ['compC', {comp: CComponent, data: 'C'}]
]
```

The way I thought of doing it was with 3 if else statements like:

```
if (compName === 'compA') {
    (<compA>comp.instance).foo('abcd');
} else if (compName === 'compB') {
    (<compB>comp.instance).foo('abcd');
} else if (compName === 'compC') {
    (<compC>comp.instance).foo('abcd');
}
```

But that's really not beautiful, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define an interface with your `foo` function:

```
interface WithFoo {
  foo: (s: string): void
}
```

2. Implement this interface in your components:

```
@Component()
class CompA implements WithFoo {
  foo(s: string): void {...} 
}
```

3. Update `myMap` with a narrow type for your component:

```
type MyMap = Map<string, {component: Type<WithFoo>, data: string}>;
```

Now

- `this.myMap.get(compName).component` has a type of `Type<WithFoo>`
- `componentFactory` has type `ComponentFactory<WithFoo>`
- `comp` has type `ComponentRef<WithFoo>`
- and finally `comp.instance` has type `WithFoo` - so you can call `.foo(data)` on it